# Select last child or sibling of certain element type using Prototype

Tags: prototype, selector

How do I select the last sibling or child instance of a certain type of element.

For example, if I have a , I'd like to select the last instance of a child  tag, but not the very last child element, which could be soemthing other than an  tag, for instance, a

Example:

```
<div id="parent">
   <span id="a"></span>
   <a id="b"></a>
   <a id="c"></a>
   <ul id="d">...</u>
</div>
```

The code should search `#parent` and return `<a id="c"></a>`.

Need to do this using Protytype, not jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found:

```
$$('.parent')[1].select('tbody > tr').last().down()....
```

Problem was when there's more than one instance of `.parent`, a specific instance needs to be targeted, and last element could be a non UI element, like a `<script>` tag. This solution allows to target a specific instance using an index, in this case `[1]`and target the last instance of a specific kind of element, in this case a `tr`.